# visibleWhen menuContribution showing up wrongly

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have created an eclipse menucontribution in my plugin which should show up ONLY when rightclicking a project that has a specific nature:

```
<menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions">
     <menu
           icon="ico/full/obj16/icon-logo-composer.png"
           id="com.dubture.composer.lib.ui.menu"
           label="Composer">
        <visibleWhen
              checkEnabled="false">
           <iterate>
              <adapt
                    type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
                 <and>
                    <test
                          property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature"
                          value="com.dubture.composer.core.composerNature">
                    </test>
                 </and>
              </adapt>
           </iterate>
        </visibleWhen>
     </menu>
  </menuContribution>
```

The visibleWhen condition seems to work only when right-clicking a project. The menu is only shown when the project has the specified nature.

However, when i right-click somewhere else (for example in some empty area in the project explorer or inside the problems view), the menu entry will show up despite the `adapt` condition.

Anyone knows how to restrict it to right clicking on projects only?

Answer (score 0):

the `test` property is used by [PropertyTester](http://www.robertwloch.net/2011/01/eclipse-tips-tricks-property-testers-with-command-core-expressions/)

if you add your menucontribution to  `popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions`, I believe it could show everywhere, you should restrict to `popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu` unless required otherwise

this snippet uses commands but I think you can try to mix with your requirements to see if it works

```
<menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu">
 <command
       commandId="COMMANDID"
       icon="icons/icon.png"
       label="LABEL"
       style="push">
    <visibleWhen
          checkEnabled="false">
       <iterate
             ifEmpty="false"
             operator="and">
          <instanceof
                value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
          </instanceof>
       </iterate>
    </visibleWhen>
 </command>
</menuContribution>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. When i change the locationURI to `popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu`, the menu entry doesn't show up at all. I've tried all sort of variations, for example `popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer?after=additions` but it won't show up. 

I'm trying to add the menu entry to the PHP explorer, maybe the `popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer` is not applicable to the PHP explorer?

Comment: please try with that specific PHP explorer locationURI (if it differs from the one I mentioned popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu)